# How do I hide the warning from Clippy about "unneeded unit expression" when using Substrate's decl_event?

Tags: rust, substrate

Having source code like in Substrate framework:

```
decl_event!(
    pub enum Event<T>
    where
        AccountId = <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
        ChipBalance = <T as Config>::ChipBalance,
    {
        /// Buy chips event
        BuyChips(AccountId, ChipBalance),
        /// Redemption amount with chips event
        Redemption(AccountId, ChipBalance),
        /// Pledge chips
        Reserve(AccountId, ChipBalance),
        /// Cancel pledge chips
        Unreserve(AccountId, ChipBalance),
        /// Transfer the chips in the pledge to others
        RepatriateReserved(AccountId, AccountId, ChipBalance),
    }
);
```

From `cargo clippy` I got:

```
warning: unneeded unit expression
  --> pallets/gamecenter/src/lib.rs:58:1
   |
58 | / decl_event!(
59 | |     pub enum Event<T>
60 | |     where
61 | |         AccountId = <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
...  |
66 | |     }
67 | | );
   | |__^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::unused_unit)]` on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#unused_unit
   = note: this warning originates in the macro `$crate::__decl_generic_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

There is any better solution to hide the warning that creation of custom rule for Clippy lints?

Comment: Can you add `#[allow(clippy::unused_unit)]` on the call to `decl_event`?

Comment: Forgive the stupid question: this is good to have no? It's letting you know that you have unused events IIUC. So better to resolve that or remove/comment out unused ones?

Comment: No stupid questions.. but the truth is that the events are used.. ;/ that is not an unneeded code, that is why the question, without using the code I could just delete it ;-) but it is not so simple ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is due to the unit in the `From<Event> for ()` implementation.
This could fix it:

```
diff --git a/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/event.rs b/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/event.rs
index c4f7aeffa7..ec38c83b8b 100644
--- a/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/event.rs
+++ b/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/event.rs
@@ -133,7 +133,7 @@ pub fn expand_event(def: &mut Def) -> proc_macro2::TokenStream {
                #deposit_event
 
                impl<#event_impl_gen> From<#event_ident<#event_use_gen>> for () #event_where_clause {
-                       fn from(_: #event_ident<#event_use_gen>) -> () { () }
+                       fn from(_: #event_ident<#event_use_gen>) -> () {}
                }
 
                impl<#event_impl_gen> #event_ident<#event_use_gen> #event_where_clause {
diff --git a/frame/support/src/event.rs b/frame/support/src/event.rs
index eb666b6f02..b11166d1c6 100644
--- a/frame/support/src/event.rs
+++ b/frame/support/src/event.rs
@@ -140,7 +140,7 @@ macro_rules! decl_event {
                        )*
                }
                impl From<Event> for () {
-                       fn from(_: Event) -> () { () }
+                       fn from(_: Event) -> () {}
                }
                impl Event {
                        #[allow(dead_code)]
```